# what is the cause of my GA plot only shows straight lines

Tags: r, function, plot, genetic-algorithm, fitness

i have no idea, Is this plot appropriate because the fitness function I created is like that? [output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3XUf.png)

here is the code:

```
library(GA)
frame_uji <-  data.matrix(data_uji)
sum_fu <- matrix(0, nrow = 350, ncol = 1)
sum_fu <- c(rowSums(frame_uji))

setup <- function(x)
{   

    output_fitness <- numeric()
    for (i in 1:350) {
        output_fitness <- c(output_fitness, 1 / (1 + sum_fu[i])) 
    }
    
    output_fitness
}

gann <- ga(type = "real-valued", population = , fitness = setup, lower = 1, upper = 5, 
           selection = gareal_rwSelection, crossover = gareal_spCrossover, 
           mutation = gareal_rsMutation, popSize = 350, maxiter = 350, 
           pcrossover = 0.6 , pmutation = 0.1, run = 30)
summary(gann)
plot(gann)
```

note:
whereas the code I want to display is like [this (https://rpubs.com/Argaadya/550805)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZAc3.png), [fitness_function from web rpubs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCjhF.png).
and this is a mathematical equation that I applied [fitness_math_equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZzgr.png);

if i separate the setup function in another chunk, it looks like this['output_fitness'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwUqX.png)

[frame_uji](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDHMf.png);[data_uji](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSkUC.png)

Comment: just do `output_fitness <- 1/sum(sum_fu)`

Comment: We cannot replicate this problem without the dataset. Please provide a reproducible dataset as an example (or a link to or subset of object data_uji).  That said, this error sounds like you are trying to overwrite an existing object of a different size. I ran your code using `data(mtcars)` and did not get any errors.

Comment: Note that the function does not even use the passed argument. What the purpose of `x` if its note used?.

Comment: okie dokie then, thanks @Onyambu

Comment: @JessicaBurnett when you execute the code the plot looks the same as this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3XUf.png

Comment: Yes, but fitness is constant at  0.0030

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.